# Why Pointer contains some trash?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, raii

I have the following code snippet:

```
size_t size = 5;
std::vector<char> container(size, 'd');

std::copy(container.begin(), container.begin() + size,
    std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " ")); // d d d d d

auto ptr = containter.data();
//ptr == dddddTRASHTRASH why??

char* str_ = new char[size + 1];
memcpy(str_, container.data, size * sizeof(char));

std::cout << str_ << std::endl; // dddddTRASHTRASHTRASH!!!!
```

I don't understand, why my pointer contains not only `d`. How to create pointer with `5` symbols of `d` with `RAII`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `container.data()` is not null-terminated, so that pointer doesn't point to a C-style string. You've put 5 `d`s there, but after those bytes is just unallocated memory. When you try to stream it, it'll just keep going until one of those unallocated bytes happens to be a `\0`.

In order to print a `const char*` validly, it has to end with a `\0`. You can verify that with:

```
size_t size = 5;
std::vector<char> container(size, 'd');

container.push_back('\0');
std::cout << container.data();
```

Same thing for `str_`. You allocated enough memory for the null-terminator, you just had to add it:

```
char* str_ = new char[size + 1];
memcpy(str_, container.data, size * sizeof(char));
str_[size] = '\0'; // need this
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... why my pointer contains not only `d`

Well, as Barry demonstrated, your pointer actually contains only `d`s

And about your second question,

> How to create pointer with 5 symbols of d with RAII?

You can use an unique_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    size_t size = 5;
    std::vector<char> container(size, 'd');

    std::copy(container.begin(), container.begin() + size,
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " ")); // d d d d d
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> p(new char[size]);
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
        p[i] = 'd';

    for(size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
        std::cout << p[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(By the way, your code snippet doesn't compile)